# How to dynamically reference a "partial template" in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, templates

I want to make use of an "external reference" in Word. (for anyone that knows AutoCAD, I want XREF abilities in Word)

Essentially I have a custom "header" that I want included in a whole pile of documents... that all reference a single file... such that if my address, logo, tagline, phone, fax or email changes, I update the one file, and all of the other 101 files that use it automatically update when I next open/use them.

I'm using Office 2007 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered for you :)

Do that:
1) Create a DOC with your header (for example: SCUNLIFFE etc.; you can use formatting)
2) Save it (for example: Header.doc)
3) Open a document
4) (Location for Office 2003; 2007 would have similar) Insert > Field > IncludeText
5) In name of URL, put Header.doc

Some notes:
- I did not try to use a file from another folder. Try it and post your resulto for that here :)
- You can use also TXT files. I did not try with another filetypes
- In M$ Office, you have to manually update the filed every time you opens the document (right button of mouse on it > update field). In OpenOffice, it asks you every time you opens the DOC
- In M$ Office, it insert a new line after the field. In OpenOffice, some fields do not appear (from DOC for example) and some order of text is changed